# How to bulk insert/update lots of data in the correct way?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, dbcontext, change-tracking

Following thing boggles my mind:

I have to bulk insert a lot of changes, some are inserts some are updates. I am not sure how to do it the best way.

Logic looks something like this:

```cs
public class Worker
{
   
    public void Run(){
       var mailer = new Mailer();

       HashSet<DbElements> dbElementsLookUp = new HashSet<DbElement>(dbContext.DbElements);
       List<Element> elements = GetSomeChangesFromSomewhere();

       var dbElementsToSave = new List<DbElements>();
 
       foreach(var element in elements)
       {
          CreateOrUpdateDbElement(element, dbElementsToSave);   

          // Sends some data based on the element - due to legacy implementation it uses its own context
          mailer.SendSomeLogging(element);
       }

       try
       {
           dbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
           dbContext.Set<DbElement>().AddRange(dbElementsToSave);
           dbContext.SaveChanges();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
            LogErrors(e);
       }
    }

    private CreateOrUpdateDbElement(ElementDto element, HashSet<DbElement> lookUp, List<DbElement> dbElementsToSave) 
    {
       var entity = lookUp.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == element.Id);
  
       if(element is not null)
       {
           entity.SomeProperty = element.SomeProperty;
           dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
           dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
           dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
       }
       else 
       {
           dbElementsToSave.Add(new DbElement
                {
                    SomeProperty = element.SomeProperty,
                    CreationDate = DateTime.Now
                });
       }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what's the best way to do this, especially for the DetectChanges. Is it save to   disable the autodetectchanges and call the detectchanges outside of the foreach. I am working with a lot of data and due to the legacy implementation it is pretty slow because for each mail there is a write operation on the database. It actually works on another instance of the context so it does not interfer with the saving of the objects of dbelements.

Is it better to add the entities to update to another list and do the same as for the adding of entities?

Comment: There's no such thing as bulk update. Bulk insert is a very specific SQL command that uses minimal logging to insert lots of records into a table. That doesn't involve ORMs at all. The way this is done is different in every database. In SQL Server you can use the SqlBulkCopy class

Comment: When you use an ORM like EF, the *best* you can hope for is executing multiple modification commands in a single script. Each operation will still be fully logged. What you avoid is executing N calls to the database for N operations

Comment: In ETL scripts, the data coming from a CSV, flat file or another database is inserted into a staging table that's identical if possible with the target table. An `UPDATE taget FROM source INNER JOIN target` is used to update existing rows. `INSERT .. SELECT FROM source LEFT JOIN target on target.ID=source.ID where target.ID IS NULL` is used to find new rows and insert them *after* the UPDATE

Comment: If I understand that correctly - even if I shift the execution to right before the save changes call (e.g. detectchanges) the amount of operations will be the same as I would do a save changes after every change of a data row, because every update of a data row is a separate sql execution?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You *can* do a bulk update, you just insert new data into a temp table or TVP, then `merge`

Comment: If it blows your mind, hand the wheel off to someone who already invented it: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions - It works well. Probably worth noting that sending the emails is highly likely going to be slower than updating the db (even one row at a time) to record that they've been sent. Are you optimizing prematurely?

Comment: @Charlieface that's not a bulk update at all. That's the staging table I described, only with worse statistics (TVPs have no statistics and are assumed to have 1 row) and no atomicity - MERGE isn't atomic and [causes a *lot* of problems due to numerous bugs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). The operations are fully logged too

Comment: @CaiusJard if you read the description of that project you'll find that nothing new was done - SqlBulkCopy is used for bulk inserts and there are no bulk updates. Just MERGE, with its problems. Why not use these directly and avoid the overhead of EF Core? There are no objects in a BULK INSERT, just rows.

Comment: @codlix no. When you call `SaveChanges` all changes collected and sent to the database, in a single transaction. That's a lot faster than sending individual changes. There's no reason to keep enabling and disabling tracking either, nothing is executed until you call `SaveChanges`. A BULK INSERT though isn't a batch of many inserts, it's a special operation using [minimal logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlserverstorageengine/bulk-import-optimizations-minimal-logging), logging entire data pages instead of individual transactions

Comment: @codlix that's why there's no bulk update or delete - when the modified rows only affect some rows in a page, it's impossible to log, commit or rollback an entire page at a time. On top of that, your code is trying to do remotely what the server would do locally - check keys against an index. In your case you load the data over the network into a HashSet "index". That alone is a *lot* slower than working in the server.

Comment: @codix check [Efficient Updating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating) in the docs. It shows how to control the batch size used by `SaveChanges` and describes the *real* bulk update - a single `UPDATE` SQL call that affects multiple rows. `UPDATE ... FROM .. JOIN` comes close if you need to combine data from source and target

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I meant to say you can do an update in bulk (all at once), which EF does not do. Using TF2453 you get correct cardinality for a TVP. `merge` without a transaction is as atomic as separate `insert/update/delete` within a transaction (because of implicit transaction per statement) and depends on isolation level. The benefit is that you only need to scan the two tables once. You could still do a bulk `insert/update/delete` if you so wish, upates and deletes are always fully logged. Most `merge` bugs have been fixed.

Comment: @Charlieface that's still not atomic and `most` means you'll run into the unfixed ones by next Tuesday. Like the one where including the PK fields in `UPDATE` will result in a `duplicate key` error. Even though there are no duplicates and the values don't really change.  So even `UPDATE` isn't exactly atomic. `BULK` has a very specific meaning, and even if you don't consider logging, what's the point of using EF at all in an ETL job? As for EF Extensions, if you check the source you'll see it converts the data to a DataTable, essentially double-caching it. That's bad

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're quite right, I probably wouldn't use EF or EF Extensions for high performance ETL, I never said I would. I would probably do it with a custom script, via TVP for a small number of rows, or temp table and `SqlBulkCopy` for a big job (I find the latter a bit more cumbersome, and slower for just a few rows). I don't disagree that EF is the wrong tool for the job here.

Comment: @Charlieface as for the bulk updates - guess what the extensions do. Create a temp table, fill it with SqlBulkCopy, then merge. While using a DataTable, thus loading and double-caching the data in memory. A *far* better solution would be to avoid EF altogether, create an IDataReader over the original data and pass that to SqlBulkCopy. CsvHelper or ExcelDataReader return an IDataReader already. FastMember's ObjectReader does the same over any `IEnumerable<>`